# Error: Creating a state object during composition without using remember [UnrememberedMutableState from androidx.compose.runtime]

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In my code I call a composable function:

```
ShowSomeComposable(
    modifier = Modifier,
    isActive = mutableStateOf(true),
)
```

and I can compile this and run locally. But the Lint check on my CI system complains:

> myFile.kt:147: Error: Creating a state object during composition
> without using remember [UnrememberedMutableState from
> androidx.compose.runtime]
> isActive = mutableStateOf(true),

So how can I replace?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert yet, but from what I see here
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables

Would suggest your code to work as:

```
var isActiveValue by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

ShowSomeComposable(
    modifier = Modifier,
    isActive = isActiveValue,
)
```

This showed me warnings at first, and treatment is to check you have these imports (could be added by IDEA suggested actions or manually)

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a mutableState here and not a simple boolean?

I mean, most of the time, when I use a `mutableStateOf`, I use it in a viewModel or directly inside the composable function. For instance :

```
var booleanVar by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
```